# log4net - getting appenders specific to only one logger

Tags: logging, log4net, log4net-appender

I'm looking for a way to get all appenders attached to one logger instance.

I tried:

```
Hierarchy hierarchy = LogManager.GetRepository() as Hierarchy;
hierarchy.GetAppenders()
```

as per documentation this returns all appenders for all loggers currently configured.

When I try this:

```
LogManager.GetLogger("MyLoggerName").Logger.Repository.GetAppenders();
```

I get the same result.

I would like to retrieve only appenders attached to one logger ("MyLoggerName" in this case)

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you call the following code

```
LogManager.GetLogger("MyLoggerName").Logger.Repository.GetAppenders();
```

you are in fact asking the exact same data as `hierarchy.GetAppenders()` because `Hierarchy` inherits `LoggerRepositorySkeleton`, which implements `ILoggerRepository`, the type returned by `Logger.Repository`.

You can however get the list of "first level" appenders by using the `Logger` class that lives in the `Hierarchy` namespace:

```
var h = LogManager.GetRepository() as Hierarchy;
var l = h.GetLogger("MyLoggerName", h.LoggerFactory);
// do something with the l.Appenders property
```

You will have to handle special cases like bufefring or filtering appenders from there