# Log4Net multi-tenancy

Tags: log4net

I have read through quite a few StackOverflow questions and tried multiple options.
I have different databases per tenant and am trying to get a ILog with an appender for a specific database.
I have successfully created an AdoNetAppender with the correct db connection string and gotten it into the log4net repository root.

However, when I ask LogManager for a new ILog, it gives me one with no appenders.  If I look at the ILog instance's parent's root, it has the AdoNetAppender I added.  What am I doing wrong?

```
Hierarchy h = (Hierarchy)LogManager.GetRepository();
var adoAppender = Log4NetAdoAppenderHelper.LoadADONetAppender(service.GetBoxDbConnectionString());
h.Root.AddAppender(adoAppender);
log4net.Config.BasicConfigurator.Configure(h);

//Neither of these work to get an appender on the ILog (_logger1 or _logger2)
var _logger1 = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger("log4net-default-repository", "AdoNetAppender");
var _logger2 = log4net.LogManager.GetRepository().GetLogger(typeof(AdoNetAppender).FullName);
```

Some of the StackOverflow Q/As I've looked at extensively and tried code from are:
[log4net - getting appenders specific to only one logger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25364535/log4net-getting-appenders-specific-to-only-one-logger)

[How to configure log4net programmatically from scratch (no config)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769983/how-to-configure-log4net-programmatically-from-scratch-no-config)

[Enable file logging for log4net from code instead of from configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436713/enable-file-logging-for-log4net-from-code-instead-of-from-configuration)

[Configure log4net RollingFileAppender in code rolling once per application start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11801899/configure-log4net-rollingfileappender-in-code-rolling-once-per-application-start/11801900#11801900)

I'm not sure why LogManager doesn't add the configured AdoNetAppender to the ILog object it gives me and am having trouble finding more on that functionality.

Comment: This link was a lot of help when making the method (2nd line above) to make the appender:
https://csharp.hotexamples.com/examples/log4net.Appender/AdoNetAppender/-/php-adonetappender-class-examples.html

Comment: OK, was able to add the appender to the logger:
Might not need any of the root level / hierarchy stuff:
var myLogger = LogManager.GetLogger("whatever name you want");
Logger l = (Logger)myLogger.Logger;
l.AddAppender(adoAppender);

Comment: Then to see how healthy your appender is / what is actually happening behind the scenes:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/756125/how-to-track-down-log4net-problems